# Launching app from XCode vs from Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I just rewrote some code that uploads audio files to s3 using NSURLSession's background configuration. When launching my app from XCode (on my connected device - NOT the simulator), everything works great. When I launch the app by tapping the icon on the disconnected device, my NSURLSessionUploadTask doesn't upload and doesn't trigger any of its callbacks. Network connectivity isn't the problem.

If I understood better the difference between launching from XCode and launching from the device, I think I could figure it out. Right now, I'm at a loss. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Generally this should not happen.just connect device with you PC and again run with breakpoints to check.may be you have not install latest build

Comment: I've tried deleting and reinstalling the app - it's definitely the same build. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Could you create fresh test project only with that piece of code and prove that exactly the launch type of the app (Xcode or device directly) defines whether `NSURLSession` will work or no?

Comment: "When I launch the app by tapping the icon on the disconnected device" When you do that, is the app really launching from scratch? Or is it just coming back to frontmost?

Comment: Yeah, I'm force quitting the app each time. Azat - I've been using Crashlytics to debug from device launch and NSLog when launched from XCode - I can see exactly where it's failing (callbacks not firing after [uploadTask resume]. I've been looking for documentation on what exactly happens when launching from XCode, but can't find anything that's helped so far. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The discretionary property of NSURLSessionConfiguration apparently causes divergent behavior depending on whether you launch your app from XCode or the device itself.

```
sessionConfiguration.discretionary = YES;   // Deleted this.
```